# auto update or have a update mode like windows

Tags: android, operating-system, updates

Is it possible to auto update or have a update mode like windows to any new secure new version of android on any machine or device like windows 10 perrinial upgrades. Currently I am stuck with a lower version of android when the warranty expires for OS support for the device